# Why the default resultType of MyBatis countByExample is java.lang.Long

Tags: integer, mybatis, long-integer

Using MyBatis Generator 1.3.5, found out the resultType of countByExample is Long.

However in previous version it was Integer (I don't remember the version exactly).
Of course I can change it back to Integer. But wondering why it happens..
It doesn't make any senses to me. Because countByExampleRange is still Integer.

Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 2):

Refer this issue on Mybatis:- https://github.com/mybatis/generator/issues/125

It is possible that tables can have more than 2 Billion rows(Integer) and to tackle that issue they changed it to Long.

Comment: Thanks, now it makes perfect sense